# Exist a way in Wordpress to print a custom breadcrumbs that display all your path navigate?

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I tried to use some plugins (Yoast Seo Included) but it doesn't display all my Navigation. I customized my theme and I get a bad display with my CPT.

For example, if I navigate on my website starting to home page and I click next for page, I would like to display all my path navigate like that.

Home << Page that I clicked << Page 2 that i clicked << Page 3 that i clicked...

I just wanna know if exist this way.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the **localStorage** for example

```
var history = {};
var items = []
history.items = items;

var title_page = 'Page 1';
var url_page = 'google.fr';

if (localStorage.getItem("historyNavigation") === null) {
    var history = {};
    var items = []
    history.items = items;
} else {
    var history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("historyNavigation"));
    var item = {
        "title_page": title_page,
        "url_page": url_page,
    }
    history.items.push(item);
}

localStorage.setItem('historyNavigation', JSON.stringify(history));
```

I don't know if my script will work but in the idea you can run this on each page and keep the last 5 pages. Then, in ajax, for example you return the value of the array and you build your breadcrumbs.

Enjoy

Comment: Hi my friend.

Thanks for your quick answer.

So, i try to insert this script on all my Wordpress page with script src? 

And how can i print it in my header?

Comment: Use cookies if you want, it may be easier to build your breadcrumb.
You recover the last 3 entries in your cookie then you display them

var [2] > var [1] > var [0]